# PHP fwrite() to socket - operation not permitted?

Tags: php, fwrite, fsockopen

I'm making a simple utility in PHP to control my Minecraft server via UDP:

```
$fp = fsockopen('udp://host', 'port', $errno, $errstr);
if (!$fp)
    error("Unable to connect!");
else {
    fwrite($fp, $data['command'].':user:pass');
    stream_set_timeout($fp, 5);
    error(fread($fp, 128));
    fclose($fp);
}
```

For some reason fwrite is throwing this error:

> Notice: fwrite() [function.fwrite]: send of 20 bytes failed with errno=1 Operation not permitted in /homepages/44/d217581656/htdocs/xenforo/util/remoterestart/interface.php on line 22

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say you're probably not permitted to use sockets on your server.  This is a fairly common thing to disable on most hosts.

Run a `phpinfo()` and see if there is any `socket` functions which are disabled, or contact your host and just ask.

Comment: What confuses me though is I can open the socket fine, it is just writing to it that won't work

Comment: They may only be disabling writing.